# text-overflow property custom style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Application is built on angular. In a component, there is a div inside which there is a text. `<div>abcdefghijklmnop<div>`

Based on the screen size, it should show completely or it should clipped. For this I have found that there is a property '`text-overflow`', which clipped the text like `abcde...`. But the requirement is we have to clip the text in other way,

`<first 3 character>...<last 3 character>`

So it should look like `abc...nop`. How can we achieve this? Browser is chrome.

Comment: What are the window breakpoints that you're looking for and what's the expected behavior on those breakpoints?

Comment: use case for an angular pipe I would say

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this via mediaquery or css completely. If using angular, how should we approach this? @AkberIqbal

Comment: @SiddAjmera Breakpoints will be like that in bootstrap, i think its 5. Also, Bootstrap also linked in this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a attribute directive like bellow to do this. For more details please refer [Angular DOC](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Please Note: You could improve this directive as you wish. This directive is only giving you the basis to implement that feature.

Directive:

```typescript
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClip]'
})
export class ClipDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let text: string = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;

    if(text.length > 6) {
      const first3 = text.slice(0, 3);
      const last3 = text.slice(text.length - 3)

      this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML =  `${first3}...${last3}`;
    }
  }

}
```

HTML:

```html
<div appClip="">abcdefghijklmnop</div>
```

[Working DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lknzee)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. How can we apply logic like if we do have space constraints then clip the innerHTML, otherwise not. Space constraints can be width of the current div element, and screen size, like in phones if we open, it should clip otherwise not.

Comment: yes you will able to do it please follow the basis structure of this directive. you could get the div element width and all by using `this.el.nativeElement`. Manipulate the things the way you want. I only gave you the basis answer to clip your text :). For more info follow [this link about attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)